# Check_MK - Custom check params specified in wato not being given to check function

Tags: check-mk

I am working on a check_mk plugin and can't seem to get the WATO specified params passed to the check function when it runs for one check in particular...

- The check param rule shows in WATO
- It writes correct looking values to rules.mk
- Clicking the Analyze check parameters icon from a hosts service discovery shows the rule as active.
- The check parameters displayed in service discovery show the title from the WATO file so it seems like it is associating things correctly.

Running `cmk -D <hostname>` shows the check as always having the default values though.

I have been staring at it for awhile and am out of ideas.

Check_MK version: 1.2.8p21 Raw

Bulk of check file:

```
factory_settings["elasticsearch_status_default"] = {
    "min": (600, 300)
}

def inventory_elasticsearch_status(info):
    for line in info:
        yield restore_whitespace(line[0]), {}

def check_elasticsearch_status(item, params, info):
    for line in info:
        name = restore_whitespace(line[0])
        message = restore_whitespace(line[2])

        if name == item:
            return get_status_state(params["min"], name, line[1], message, line[3])

check_info['elasticsearch_status'] = {
  "inventory_function"      : inventory_elasticsearch_status,
  "check_function"          : check_elasticsearch_status,
  "service_description"     : "ElasticSearch Status %s",
  "default_levels_variable" : "elasticsearch_status_default",
  "group"                   : "elasticsearch_status",
  "has_perfdata"            : False
}
```

Wato File:

```
group = "checkparams"
#subgroup_applications = _("Applications, Processes & Services")

register_check_parameters(
    subgroup_applications,
    "elasticsearch_status",
    _("Elastic Search Status"),
    Dictionary(
        elements = [
            ( "min",
              Tuple(
                  title = _("Minimum required status age"),
                  elements = [
                      Age(title = _("Warning if below"), default_value = 600),
                      Age(title = _("Critical if below"), default_value = 300),
                  ]
            ))
        ]
    ),
    None,
    match_type = "dict",
)
```

Entry in rules.mk from WATO rule:

```
checkgroup_parameters.setdefault('elasticsearch_status', [])

checkgroup_parameters['elasticsearch_status'] = [
  ( {'min': (3600, 1800)}, [], ALL_HOSTS ),
] + checkgroup_parameters['elasticsearch_status']
```

Let me know if any other information would be helpful!

*EDIT*: pls help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posted question [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/6mn14t/check_mk_custom_check_params_specified_in_wato/) as well and the mystery got solved.

I was matching the WATO rule to item `None` (5th positional arg in the WATO file), but since this check had multiple items inventoried under it (none of which had the id `None`) the rule was applying to the host, but not to any of the specific service checks.

Fix was to replace that param with:

```
TextAscii( title = _("Status Description"), allow_empty = True),
```